# MS Word documents changing to .cpio files and then to .zip files

Tags: macos, ms-office, microsoft, archive-utility

I really need help with this issue: whenever I try to open a word document file from my Mac, the archive utility application opens up and turns the .doc file into a .cpio file and if I click on that it then turns into a .zip file.

I've tried to research and even called Mac Support and they were not helpful. I just want my MS Word files to open up when I double click on them. I don't know how to stop the archive utility from opening up. It's a repetitive cycle of .cpio file to .zip file to .cpio and so on.

If anyone knows how to fix this issue please let me know.

Comment: If you right click on a .doc in Finder and choose Get Info what shows in Open with... ?

Comment: When I did that it said Open with: Archive Utility. I changed it to Microsoft Word and it worked. I just want to thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction. If you add this as an answer, I'll mark it as correct! :)

Answer (score 1):

When a document opens with the wrong app the first thing to do is see what macOS thinks should happen.

- In Finder find a document
- Right click on it and choose Get Info
- Look at what `Open with...` shows
- If it is the wrong application alter it to be the correct one e.f. Word in this case. You might want to Change all as well.

  - If it is the correct app then more investigation needs to be done.